# Figma pixels differs from Photoshop pixels?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, figma

I have designed a landing page for a website for one of my client. I designed it in Figma(Online UI design tool) and have exported the whole artboard with **1x** resolution with the size (**W**:1400px, **H**:3900px). And now want to add it as an portfolio image on the upwork portfolio.
When I upload the image it says "Image resloution can't exceed 4000px by 4000px".

So, I studied [this](https://support.upwork.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016144974-Enhance-Your-Profile#:%7E:text=The%20minimum%20dimensions%20for%20images,4000px%20width%20by%204000px%20height.). Now if I want to keep the size within the brackets let's say (**W**:1000px, **H**:"X"px) where **"X"** can not exceed more than 4000px (in my case it is 3900px).

So, how can I keep these dimensions without ruining the quality of the image?

I have tried it in photoshop but it pixelated the image.
Any help would be very much appreacited!

Comment: What file type have you exported as? .JPG, PNG, PDF ?

What does the file's meta data state it's size as ?

Comment: I exported both .png and .jpg with 1x scale and being jpg it's size was 2.3mb.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using photoshop then did you make the layer to a **Smart Object** ?
2. Second thing, You canvas is 1400 PX by 3900 PX that is your canvas size, the size changes as you add elements to that canvas.

In other words if you have a canvas 100 x 100 Px and you will export it after all the work done in that, it might vary designs to designs.

```
The solution for this would be to decrease the image sizes when you use them.
```